# Modal POP scope not retain value

Tags: angularjs

I have a html page there is one button. on click this button a angular modal pop is open. we have sent some data from parent window to pop window. There are three kendo dropdown on pop window. data is sent from parent window to popup will be selected value in drop down. but data sent,  becomes blank on load of pop window, even data successfully sent to pop window..
My parent page code is below :

```
  $scope.openPOPWindow = function (condition) {
    var objRegelDetails = {
        //param1: $scope.modelObject[condition.ParameterFejl1Model],
        //param2: $scope.modelObject[condition.ParameterFejl2Model],
        //param3: $scope.modelObject[condition.ParameterFejl3Model],
        param1: '13',
        param2: '14',
        param3: '15',
        conditionKode: condition.ConditionKode
    };
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        backdrop: 'static',
        templateUrl: './RuleEngine/UI/RegelConditionPopUp',
        controller: RegelContrl.RegelConditionController,
        keyboard: false,
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return objRegelDetails;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        if (!IsNullorEmpty(selectedItem)) {
            alert(selectedItem.Param1);
        }
    }, function () {
    });
};
```

and POP window controller is below :

```
  var adm = angular.module('AdminModule');
  adm.controller('RegelConditionPopUpCtrl', ['$scope', 'RegelService', '$q',      '$rootScope', '$modalInstance', 'items', 'DirtyFlagPopup', 'SagService', 'localize', 'toaster', 'ValidationService',
 function ($scope, RegelService, q, $rootScope, $modalInstance, items,     DirtyFlagPopup, SagService, localize, toaster, ValidationService) {
 function loadhandlingType() {
    var paramTypes = RegelService.GetParamTypes();
    //angular.element('#dvLoadingUA').show();
    q.all([paramTypes]).then(function (responses) {

        if (responses[0].length > 0) {
            $scope.drpParamType.data(responses[0]);
        }
        else {
            $scope.drpParamType.data([]);
        }

        //angular.element('#dvLoadingUA').hide();
    });
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.close();
};

$scope.PushRegelConditionParamData = function () {
    var selectedData = {
        Param1: '',
        Param2: '',
        Param3: ''
    };
    selectedData.Param1 = angular.element('#ddlparameterOption1' + $scope.RegelConditionUID).val();
    selectedData.Param2 = angular.element('#ddlparameterOption2' + $scope.RegelConditionUID).val();
    selectedData.Param3 = angular.element('#ddlparameterOption3' + $scope.RegelConditionUID).val();
    $modalInstance.close(selectedData);
};

$scope.initializedDropDown = function () {

    $scope.drpHandlingType = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [],
        type: "json",
    });
    $scope.drpHandlingTypeOption = {
        dataSource: $scope.drpHandlingType,
        dataTextField: FindRegelEnum.TextField,
        dataValueField: FindRegelEnum.ValueField
    };

    $scope.drpParamType = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [],
        type: "json",
    });
    $scope.drpParamTypeOption = {
        dataSource: $scope.drpParamType,
        optionLabel: localize.getLocalizedString("_RE_Home_DefaultSelect_"),
        dataTextField: FindRegelEnum.TextField,
        dataValueField: FindRegelEnum.ValueField
    };

    loadhandlingType();
};

$scope.InitializeRC = function () {
    $scope.RegelConditionUID = GetUID();
    $scope.ModelData = {
        Parameter1: '',
        Parameter2: '',
        Parameter3: ''
    };
    $scope.initializedDropDown();
    $scope.ModelData.Parameter1 = items.param1,
    $scope.ModelData.Parameter2 = items.param2,
    $scope.ModelData.Parameter3 = items.param3
};

}]);
```

but problem is that on html we can see value for **ModelData.Parameter2** for a second  and than it disappear...
please tell me why scope variable not retain their values

Comment: Please take a look now..